# How to install gfortran in CentOS offline?

Tags: linux, gcc, centos, gfortran

In order to run a program I need SSH to a cluster. But the cluster doesn't have a `gfortran` compiler which is needed by my program. As  there is not network in the cluster I can't install `gfortran` through `yum install gcc-gfortran`. I have tried to install a new `gcc` offline, but some errors occurred during the `make` stage, what's worse, I couldn't find any solution to these errors. So I'd like to know whether there is a better way to install `gfortran` in `CentOS` offline?

P.S.: My computer's OS is Windows.

Comment: You might install `gfortran-5` on your cluster in e.g. `$HOME/soft/` by compiling it from source code. You'll need to pass `--prefix=$HOME/soft/` to `configure`

Comment: Alternatively, install Linux on your laptop and compile on that.

Comment: Do you have root access on the cluster in question to install software system-wide?

Comment: @EtanReisner I don't, so I am trying to install from source code now.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have tried to find a `gfortran` source code, but It seems that most websites suggest a installation of `gcc` with configuration `--enable-languages=fortran` which will induce errors on cluster. Is there somewhere to find the individual `gfortran` source code or I'd better install a `CentOS` on my computer and download it through command?

Comment: No, `gfortran` is part of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). So get [GCC 5.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) and configure it appropriately.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thank you, I have installed `gfortran` successfully.